# nhibernate architecture

Tags: nhibernate, architecture

Hello
I want to create my first nhibernate projet.
It will be a migration from a winform project associated with an old dataacess with no strong orm mapping.
The project is quite large so I'd like to have a good architecture from the beginning.

I will have some layer :

- Repository : Create the session from nhibernate
- Model : The bean object, basically it consists of getter / setter properties with the same name in the database

But I'll need some advices, how will you handle the operations ?
If I want to create an item should I access directly to nhibernate from the code ? Or should I create a business logic layer ?

Basically I found that simple architecture for the business layer.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateArchitecture.aspx
What is your feeling ?

Another question, it is a program with strong validation (glasses domain), where should be the validation ? in the winform project or in a business layer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say and give useful advices without seeing the project and its actual problems. Is it client-server architecture for instance? What do you mean by "quite large"? There are too many different projects to have rules which fit all.

Generally:

- In most of the cases, it is very useful to have a business layer.
- validation should be in the business layer. There is also NHibernate validation and some other validation frameworks around, which allow declarative validation.

The most common mistake I see when starting with NH is that people don't understand persistence ignorance. This means that you should write your business logic without accessing the database or NH. Changes are made on the entities, they are not "temporarily" until they get explicitly applied to the database, they get implicitly stored when the transaction gets committed. This has a huge impact to the code. In many cases, there is no "Store" or "Update" or whatever.

Comment: quite large means that a team of 5 developers will potentially develop. They work on multiple project but I estim that every year, there is 2 man full time working on the project. It is a software for glasses seller. We have only 2 layers. One for IHM, one for DataAccess and we wan't to segment more layers. Mostly it will be basic CRUD logic or specific SELECT or UPDATE (ex : SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN table2 etc.). The structures aren't complex. but there is complex logic ex : if the correction of the glas has Addition > 0 it is a special type of glas (progressive)

Comment: An example of the problem. We have a very complex form which permit to select all the item of the sell (all the part of a glasses or lens) with corrections etc. It is a tabbed form, each tab is a type of product. If we click on some options, some controls disapears etc. Difficult to maintain

Comment: and last answer, it is client server architecture. In your example, when I want to create an item, is the field populated in the winform module (ex : var item = new Item(); item.prop1 = ..; item.prop2 = ...; Item.Add(item); ) ? or in a business module (ex : Item.AddNew(prop1, prop2); and in the AddNew there is the previous code) ?

Comment: if validation is in the business layer, how is it redirected to the ihm layer ? with an exception with a specific message ? with a return code (enum style) ?

Comment: These questions are too basic and too specific to answer them here. Control disappearing is view logic, but to know what can be done when is business logic. There is always the risk to put too much into the client / view layer. When using NH, don't think in queries and CRUD, think in objects. Validation usually throws some kind of validation exception when storing. Return codes are very hard to use and maintain. I don't understand these AddNew stuff.

Comment: thank you stefan for your enlightments.  I found this architecture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379500/nhibernate-removes-dal what do you think of that ? (Or similar http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx ) I found also that piece of code http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateArchitecture.aspx

Comment: The code project "Best practices" link is the way we set up our architecture. The interesting part is that Data depends on Core, not vice versa. It actually only needs to implement interfaces known by the Core and handle the entities which are probably implemented somewhere else, as proposed in the "NHibernate removes DAL?" accepted answer.  --  By the way, we had a hard time to find out that data transfer objects (DTO's) aren't a bad idea and much cheaper to use from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SharpArchitecture. It is a very good framework for NHibernate. Very good example on how to wire everything up.

http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

Comment: I don't know it, but it seems to be designed for ASP.net. I can't see any relation to ASP in the question.

Comment: the main project is a full winform project