# nhibernate lazy loading

Tags: nhibernate

I've a problem of session when I use lazy loading in the UI layer.

My piece of code (in the DAO layer)

```
public List<Visites> GetVisitesClientQuery(string idClient)
{
     using (ISession session = Repository.TSession())
     {
        var results = (from v in session.Query<Visites>()
                       where v.Clients.Idclient == idClient
                       select v);

        return results.ToList<Visites>();
     }
}
```

I call it in the UI layer :

```
var visites = VisiteManager.Instance.GetVisitesClientQuery(lstClients.SelectedValue.ToString());
foreach (Visites v in visites)
{
    foreach (Factures f in v.Factures)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

v.Factures is a collection.

If I call it in the using it works (the session is opened) but in this case it doesn't work and I've this error.

```
Initializing[NHibernateTest.BusinessObjects.Visites#036000007935]-
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
NHibernateTest.BusinessObjects.Visites.Factures, no session or session was closed
```

Is it possible to handle a lazy loading call in the UI layer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here, is that you handle your session management inside your repository (DAO layer), which isn't a good idea.

An `ISession` implementation in NHibernate represents a '[Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)'.  A Unit Of Work needs to know the 'context' of the 'use-case' to be able to use this concept successfully.

Your repository however has no notion of the 'context' of the use case in which it (the repository) is used.
Therefore, it is not your DAO layer that should decide when to open an ISession, but it is your 'application layer' (or even your UI layer, if you do not have an Application Layer) which should do that ,  since that will be the layer that knows your context.

By doing so, you can indeed effectively use the Session as a UnitofWork.  In order to save an entity, you'll have to use the same session to save the entity, as the session that you've used to load that entity.  (Otherwise, you'll need to 'lock' the entity into the session).
Next to that, it will also solve your lazy loading problem. :)

Comment: But I thought I shouldn't use nhibernate function in my view layer ? ... I found that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379500/nhibernate-removes-dal which look relevant. I'm pretty lost with all that layer ...

Comment: Your repository implementation is your DAL.  However, this does not mean that your DAL should create your Session.  You can pass the Session to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should eager load the collections you know you will be using with
 session.Query().Fetch(x=>x.Factures).

That will load all Visites with the Factures.